# PHP: Hook class to remove inline HTML and including into another class

Tags: php, html

> May be my question title is not so well to discribe, since I am
>   confuse what to say this :( hope any moderator will help to write the
>   right title.

Here I have one core class containing all core methods with inline HTML. The system allows to override methods by extending the `core_class` using `theme_class`, but I cannot remove inline HTML since the page renders with those tags.

So I am looking for some hook where I can extends the `core_class` methods with different class (`hook_class`) and rewrite all methods without inlne HTML and return the value. Than I can instanciate that into HTML/PHP file and use own markup.

Once HTML/PHP is ready than I include it into `theme_class` somewhere. The system only consider `theme_class` as a theme file which allows to override `core_class` method.

So in short I am trying to too take out all inline HTML from `core_class` and create HTML/PHP for theme and than include theme files to `theme_class` which is extending the `core_class`.

So is there any way which allows me to do what I am looking for?

**System Core Class**

```
class core_class
{

    function class_method1()
    {
        // all php code including inline html
    }

    function class_method2()
    {
        // all php code including inline html
    }

    function class_method3()
    {
        // all php code including inline html
    }

}
```

**System Theme Class extends Core Class**

```
class theme_class extends core_class
{

    function class_method1()
    {
        // all override code for the method
    }

    function class_method2()
    {
        // all override code for the method
    }

    function class_method3()
    {
        // all override code for the method
    }

}
```

Comment: Where and what is the 'inline HTML' you are talking about?

Comment: Every function has piece of code. For instance WordPress `the_title()` is a method and the HTML wrapper is inline with php code and not even allowing to set wrapper in parameters. Now the same way entire page is getting render with this type of methods which has inline HTMLs so I want to remove all HTML and just return the value.